# Bad operand type for binary operator '^'

Tags: java, recursion

Trying to create a recursive method that raises a double value to an int power for a java course. The instructions say "However, write the code so that when n is even the method will return (x ^ (n/2))^2."

This is what I have thus far:

```
     public static double powerFaster(double x, int n) {
         if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
         } 
         else if ((n % 2) == 0) {
           return ((x ^ (n / 2.0) ^ 2.0));  //Error occurs here.
         } else {
           return x * powerFaster(x, (n - 1));
         }
     }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`^` is a XOR operator, not power. Use `Math.pow()` for power.

That said, I think you missed the point of the exercise.

You should `return powerFaster(x, n/2) * powerFaster(x, n/2);` when `n` is even (actually make one recursive call, store its result in a variable and multiply it by itself).

```
public static double powerFaster(double x, int n) {
     if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
     } 
     else if ((n % 2) == 0) {
       double pow = powerFaster(x, n/2);
       return pow * pow;
     } else {
       return x * powerFaster(x, (n - 1));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and letting me know that other tidbit. I figured I was supposed to implement a recursive method for that part but wasn't really sure the best way to do that.

Answer (score 8):

If you are doing this for speed, you want to avoid using `Math.pow` as this is the function you are trying to replace.

To get a square of a value you can do `d * d`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(powerOf(2, 9));
}

public static double powerOf(double d, int n) {
    if (n < 0) return 1 / powerOf(d, -n);

    double ret = 1;
    if (n > 1)
        ret = powerOf(d * d, n / 2);
    if (n % 2 != 0)
        ret *= d;
    return ret;
}
```

prints

```
512.0
```

Answer (score 6):

`^` is bitwise XOR, used with **integers**:

```
int a = 6; //00000110
int b = 5; //00000101
int c = a ^ b; //gives you 3 = 00000011, not 6^5
```

The operation is in the binary level:

```
00000110 //a
00000101 //b
--------- XOR
00000011
```

To perform power, use `Math.pow()`:

```
Math.pow(2.0, 1.0) //gives you 2.0
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java you should use [java.lang.Math.pow(double x, double n)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) for raising value `x` to a power of `n`

`^` is a [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator - see this [SO question](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) for more details

Answer (score 2):

On a side note don't forget that Math.pow is a really heavy operation, if you only use it for square or cube, you'd better do it with * operators or even for loops

> Mult with * operator took 4ms
>
> Mult with math pow took 717ms
>
> Mult with for loop took 4ms

Only with cube operation in a test, done a million times

Comment: Side notes should be comments not answers.

Comment: Sadly enough, I don't have enough karma to comment :/